# Image with solid color rounded background

Tags: html, css

I want to display images inside a container that has a colored background.

I want the background of the container is rounded, and the image is placed at the center.

Also, there is space between the border of the background and the image.

This is the goal:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCUvH.png)

The code so far:

```css
.circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2e374f;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.title{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/50/50" class="mx-auto d-block">
    <div class="title">
        TITLE
    </div>
</div>
```

this is what I achieved so far:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPGkG.png)

Comment: add your HTML & CSS code here

Comment: @LaljiTadhani, Hi, I just updated the question description.

Comment: You are mixing `display: flex` and `display: table-cell`. It can only be one of those. Hint: I'm 99.999% sure you don't need tables here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove `display: table-cell` rule and additionaly you can shrink the image.

```css
.circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2e374f;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

.title{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.img {
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?grayscale" class="mx-auto d-block img">
    <div class="title">
        TITLE
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check.

```css
.container-box { 
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  
}

.container-circle {
  
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.image {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Font_Awesome_5_solid_arrow-circle-right.svg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="container-circle">
    <div class="image">
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If I see correctly you want the image to be round and not the container. In this case this should help you out:

```css
.circle img {
border-radius: 50%;
max-width: 100%;
}

.circle{
    background: #2e374f;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: column;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.title{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/50/50" class="mx-auto d-block">
    <div class="title">
        TITLE
    </div>
</div>
```